# extract lzx files in the browser

Tags: javascript, chm

I am trying to make a CHM reader in JavaScript. I am trying to find way to extract data out of the LZX compression format that will work in most browsers. I also don't want to use a server-side API, because this program is supposed to work offline. Does anybody know a way to do this?

Comment: The only thing I could find was what a CHM file was or how to open it in PHP, C, and Python. The only thing for javascript was for NodeJS.

Comment: Note that the LZX compression used in CHM is altered from the original: See [Wikipedia's article on LZX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZX). You may be interested in the answer to [Using HTML Help Workshop 1.3 and HTML5 and Javascript DOM and targeting Windows 10 with HTML Help files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55174247/215552). Also note that CHM is not really used even by Microsoft any more...

Comment: Try to compile some existing source code in C or Pascal through an emscripten (or Pas2js in Pascal's case) to convert it to javascript?